# Shape of a current carrying wire

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose we have an arbitrary shaped wire carrying a current and placed on a frictionless table. What will be the ultimate shape of the wire and why? (Is there any magnetic effect?)

[image]

Comment: We know that wires with anti-parallel currents repel and parallel currents attract (how? hint: biot-savart law). What do you think will be the ultimate shape of the wire?

Comment: Even if the table is *frictionless*, you *cannot* have an ideally flexible wire that will respond to any arbitrarily small repulsions/attractions between segments. Or, you need to assume that current is very high so that repulsions/attractions are *not* sensitive to the *flexibility* and/or *weight* of the wire along the circuit. Please edit your question accordingly so that we can think of it more carefully.

Comment: Assume that the forces are not sensitive to flexibility and the wire is very light.